# Mysql - how to UPDATE table from another table with several WHERE conditions

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update, where-clause

I have 2 tables:

table1 which looks like:

> column1 | column2 | item1 | item2 | item3 | item4 | (it goes till item50)
>
> value   | value   | value | value | value | value | .........

table_to_update that looks like:

> column1 | colum2 | item
>
> value   | value  | value of item1
>
> value   | value  | value of item2
>
> value   | value  | value of item3
>
> value   | value  | value of item4
>
> value   | value  | value of item....

when I change in table1 the value of colum1 or column2 then I want these data changed in table_to_update. Note values of items 1-50 never change

So I can update value of item1 by using this PHP commands:

```
UPDATE table_to_update, table1
SET table_to_update.column1 = table1.column1, table_to_update.column2 = table1.column2
WHERE table_to_update.item = table1.item1
```

Then value of item2 with:

```
UPDATE table_to_update, table1
SET table_to_update.column1 = table1.column1, table_to_update.column2 = table1.column2
WHERE table_to_update.item = table1.item2
```

(all the same but table1.item1 is changed to table1.item2)

And do that 50 times which is obviously not very convenient

Is there a way to only have the WHERE part changed, such as something like this (which is wrong):

```
UPDATE table_to_update, table1
SET table_to_update.column1 = table1.column1, table_to_update.column2 = table1.column2
WHERE table_to_update.item = table1.item1 ("THEN") table_to_update.item = table1.item2 ("THEN") table_to_update.item = table1.item3 ....
```

Alternatively I can write commands like below for the 50 items:

```
UPDATE table_to_update, table1
SET table_to_update.column1 = table1.column1, table_to_update.column2 = table1.column2
WHERE table_to_update.item = table1.item1

UPDATE table_to_update, table1
SET table_to_update.column1 = table1.column1, table_to_update.column2 = table1.column2
WHERE table_to_update.item = table1.item2
```

but I don't know how to have them all run from 1 PHP page. It looks like I need to create 50 PHP pages with 1 statement each?

Comment: This is what happens when you have a denormalized data structure.  You should have a junction table instead of dozens of columns with the same information.

Comment: What I didn't say is table_to_update is created first based on table1. But then in table_to_update there is a 4th column in reality that is populated based on other information (and for each item). So basically I would like to keep data from this 4th column and just update column1 and column2

Comment: "It looks like I need to create 50 PHP pages with 1 statement each?" - no use a LOOP and VARIABLES in the sql statement

Comment: Right using a loop is brilliant thanks! I didn't know we could. So the code is basically: 
$x = 1;

while($x <= 50) {
$sql = "UPDATE table_to_update, table1
SET table_to_update.column1 = table1.column1, table_to_update.column2 = table1.column2
WHERE table_to_update.item = table1.item$x";
$x++;
}    (where $x++ increments $x of +1)

Comment: Ignore comment no 1 at your peril

Comment: I would love to apply a normalized data structure but I'll look into this for next project as this one if finished there was only this little thing to update following a bug that came in. I'm pretty new to php and mysql and learned by examples though hence the lack in some basic theory...

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query('SELECT * FROM table1'));

foreach ($data as $row) {

    mysql_query("UPDATE table_to_update SET column1 = '{$row['column1']}', column2 = '{$row['columnd2']}' WHERE item = '{$row['item1']}'");



}
```

I think thats where you need to be heading. But it needs more work and is not secure. If anyone wants to contribute go ahead.